# Tensorflow strategy error: Mixing different tf.distribute.Strategy objects with overrides train_step keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am having difficulties to implement a distributed strategy on my TensorFlow v2 model and I am looking for some help.
The main difference with the documentation is that my model overrides keras train_step function.
I got the distribute strategy to work with simple model or with custom training loop but I would like to avoid the latest as I prefer using model.fit which let me use keras callbacks out of the box.

There is a link to a collab model with custom train_step similar to my model https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/generative/ipynb/dcgan_overriding_train_step.ipynb

To reproduce the error, I modified the init of the model to get the network initialization and compile steps inside the strategy scope

```py
class GAN(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim):
        super(GAN, self).__init__()
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim

        strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
        with strategy.scope():
          
          self.discriminator = keras.Sequential(
              [
                  keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1)),
                  layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
                  layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
                  layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
                  layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
                  layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D(),
                  layers.Dense(1),
              ],
              name="discriminator",
          )

          self.generator = keras.Sequential(
              [
                  keras.Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,)),
                  layers.Dense(7 * 7 * 128),
                  layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
                  layers.Reshape((7, 7, 128)),
                  layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
                  layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
                  layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
                  layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
                  layers.Conv2D(1, (7, 7), padding="same", activation="sigmoid"),
              ],
              name="generator",
          )
          
          self.compile(
              d_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0003),
              g_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0003),
              loss_fn=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          )


    def compile(self, d_optimizer, g_optimizer, loss_fn):
        super(GAN, self).compile()
        self.d_optimizer = d_optimizer
        self.g_optimizer = g_optimizer
        self.loss_fn = loss_fn

    def train_step(self, real_images):
        if isinstance(real_images, tuple):
            print("debug")
            real_images = real_images[0]
        # Sample random points in the latent space
        batch_size = tf.shape(real_images)[0]
        random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))

        # Decode them to fake images
        generated_images = self.generator(random_latent_vectors)

        # Combine them with real images
        combined_images = tf.concat([generated_images, real_images], axis=0)

        # Assemble labels discriminating real from fake images
        labels = tf.concat(
            [tf.ones((batch_size, 1)), tf.zeros((batch_size, 1))], axis=0
        )
        # Add random noise to the labels - important trick!
        labels += 0.05 * tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(labels))

        # Train the discriminator
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.discriminator(combined_images)
            d_loss = self.loss_fn(labels, predictions)
        grads = tape.gradient(d_loss, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
        self.d_optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(grads, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
        )

        # Sample random points in the latent space
        random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))

        # Assemble labels that say "all real images"
        misleading_labels = tf.zeros((batch_size, 1))

        # Train the generator (note that we should *not* update the weights
        # of the discriminator)!
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.discriminator(self.generator(random_latent_vectors))
            g_loss = self.loss_fn(misleading_labels, predictions)
        grads = tape.gradient(g_loss, self.generator.trainable_weights)
        self.g_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.generator.trainable_weights))
        return {"d_loss": d_loss, "g_loss": g_loss}
```

Then run the code with:

```py
epochs = 30
gan = GAN(latent_dim=latent_dim)
gan.fit(
    dataset, epochs=epochs, callbacks=[GANMonitor(num_img=3, latent_dim=latent_dim)]
)
```

The full error message :

```py
RuntimeError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    <ipython-input-12-54a272890fa5>:78 train_step
        zip(grads, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:519 apply_gradients
        self._create_all_weights(var_list)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:702 _create_all_weights
        _ = self.iterations
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:709 __getattribute__
        return super(OptimizerV2, self).__getattribute__(name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:836 iterations
        aggregation=tf_variables.VariableAggregation.ONLY_FIRST_REPLICA)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:1040 add_weight
        aggregation=aggregation)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py:750 _add_variable_with_custom_getter
        **kwargs_for_getter)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py:145 make_variable
        shape=variable_shape if variable_shape else None)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:260 __call__
        return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:221 _variable_v1_call
        shape=shape)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:67 getter
        return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2024 creator_with_resource_vars
        created = self._create_variable(next_creator, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_strategy.py:450 _create_variable
        values.MirroredVariable, values.SyncOnReadVariable, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_utils.py:291 create_mirrored_variable
        value_list = real_mirrored_creator(**kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_strategy.py:443 _real_mirrored_creator
        v = next_creator(**kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:67 getter
        return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2856 creator
        _require_strategy_scope_strategy(strategy)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:344 _require_strategy_scope_strategy
        _wrong_strategy_scope(strategy, context)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:322 _wrong_strategy_scope
        (context.strategy, strategy))

    RuntimeError: Mixing different tf.distribute.Strategy objects: <tensorflow.python.distribute.mirrored_strategy.MirroredStrategy object at 0x7ff32ba58f60> is not <tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib._DefaultDistributionStrategy object at 0x7ff3c0ca0320>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?